# Convertir BASE64 a pdf en C#

Tags: c#, base64

Buenos días una consulta, utilizo el siguiente código para generar un pdf a partir de la codificación base64.

```
string strRutaDestino = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@"\Documento\prueba.pdf";
System.IO.FileStream output = new FileStream(strRutaDestino, FileMode.Create);
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        output.Close();
```

el problema es que se crea el pdf pero no se puede abrir, debido a que esta dañado.
me podrían ayudar, gracias.

Comment: El código está correcto. El problema podría ser que el base64 no tenga un pdf válido.

Comment: como lo pasas a base64?

Comment: byte[] buffer= Convert.FromBase64String("asasasasasasdsf");
la codificacion es de prueba ya que es muy extensa para pegarlo aca